Zero sets of sums of multivariate polynomials defined recursively with mutually disjoint support
It is difficult in general to say anything about the zero sets of a sum of two or more multivariable polyomials. However, I am interested in two special cases:

I have a family of multivariate trignometric polynomials $f_\ell,g_\ell : \mathbb R^{\ell} \to \mathbb R$. I can write $f_\ell$ and $g_\ell$ as follows: $$
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{\ell} \\
g_{\ell}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha \cos x_\ell  &  -\beta \sin x_\ell  \\
\alpha \sin x_\ell &  \beta \cos x_\ell  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{\ell-1} \\
g_{\ell-1}
\end{pmatrix} \quad \quad
\alpha , \beta \in \mathbb R^\times
$$
Here $f_{\ell-1}, g_{\ell-1}$ are to be thought to similar polynomials that depend on only the first $\ell-1$ variables. Here I have a sum of polynomials defined recursively. Can I relate the zero sets of $f_{\ell}$ and $g_{\ell}$ to that of $f_{\ell-1}$ and $g_{\ell-1}$? Can I relate topological properties of the zero set (such as the number of connected components) of $f_{\ell}$ and $g_{\ell}$ to that of $f_{\ell-1}$ and $g_{\ell-1}$?

Write the coordinates of $ \mathbb R^{\ell_1 + \cdots + \ell_n}$ as $x = (x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ Consider a polynomial $f : \mathbb R^{\ell_1 + \cdots + \ell_n} \to \mathbb R$ of the form
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i f_i(x_i), \quad \quad a_i \in \mathbb R
$$
Here I have a sum of polynomials, where each polynomial in the sum depends on mutually disjoint sets of variables. Can I relate the zero sets of $f$ to that of $f_1, \cdots, f_n$? Can I relate topological properties of the zero set (such as the number of connected components) of $f$ to that of $f_1, \cdots, f_n$?


Ultimately, I care about the number of connected components of the zero sets. The problem I am interested in combines both cases.
Does anyone know of any literature on the topological properties of the zero sets of sums of multivariate polynomials defined in these special cases?

This is the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4987455/zero-sets-of-trigonometric-polynomials-defined-recursively ?

This is an expanded version of my question on StackExchange. I am looking for recommendations of literature, which is why I decided to post it here.

OK. When you post two questions so closely related, you really ought to link each one to the other.
